# How to make multiple files with event functions work as if they were one file?

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord

I am working on a discord bot and I haven't done anything in python this complex before. I have a main .py file with a bunch of on events functions. It's starting to get very long so I would like to split this main .py file into two files so that I can keep organized. However, I do not know how to make the sub-file work properly. When I try importing the sub-file into the main one, only the sub-file runs. Is there any way to get both these files to work as if they were one?

This is what I've tried:

main.py

```
import discord
import os
import subfile
client = discord.Client()
@client.event



async def on_ready():
  print('Ready!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

subfile.py

```
import discord
import os
client = discord.Client()
@client.event



async def on_ready():
  print('Ready 2!')


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Output is "Ready 2!". Would like it to be "Ready! and "Ready 2!".

Comment: It will first wait to execute the client.run function and only then start with the main file, so I can only suggest removing the client.run in the subfile

Comment: the other thing is that as far as I know such 'subfiles' are generally not used to run themselves, they just contain functions You need to run, so in the main file You would import all the functions You need and run them there not use import to run functions, also I suggest learning about `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much!